# How bad are my hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive

I have an Ubuntu server with md RAID6 across 6 1TB HDDs connected directly to the motherboard. In the past couple of days, `smartctl-monitor` has been throwing up warnings. Here's my [`syslog` and `smartctl -a /dev/sd{ac}`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f78fa1f92703c131eeb4) output.

The temperatures are between 29°C and 34°C. Other than the errors, everything seems to be running fine.

How broken are these drives? Is there any way to find out what the actual problem is? Is it a "replace them all immediately" situation? Everything is backed up to CrashPlan, so there's no danger of data loss.

The error is `ATA bus error`, which apparently means a "chip<->device bus error". How likely is that to indicate cabling rather than, say, the drive just failing to respond? I'm presuming the most common failure modes are mechanical.

Comment: I'd want to suspect the motherboard. The disk controller might be faulty, try plugging the disks into another machine.

Comment: Don't SMART errors come from the drive itself, though?

Comment: Check the SATA cables too. The generic red ones often suck. Communication errors with the host are also registered by SMART.